# input type checkbox submit

Tags: sql, submit

I have the following code:

[image: index php code]

When someone enters an email address and press submit then i receive the email address in my database. However how can I also receive wether they check newsletter on or off?

This is the part of my **waitinglist.php**

[image: waitinglist.php]

PLease help me on this. in DB i have the table waitinglist with column waitinglist.

Comment: Add your codes in the question and not as image attachment

Answer (score 0):

In  your HTML code you can edit the code for html as shown below:-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" value=1 checked />
```

In php you can include the following code to check if the checkbox is checked or not

```
$newsletter =(isset($_POST['newsletter'])?$_POST['newsletter']:'')

if($newsletter ==1){
  some code here....
}
```

Comment: changed the html to this <form method="post" action="waitinglist.php">
<div id="otherInformation">
<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" value=1 checked />
<label for="newsletter"><span></span>Get our monthly newsletter</label>
</div>
</form>   waitinglist.php (i've added a column called newsletter in my DB)   $connect = new mysqli('x','x','x','x') or die("Unable to connect");
$sql ="INSERT INTO `robin`.`waitinglist` (`waitinglist`) VALUES ('$waitinglist')";
$sql ="INSERT INTO `robin`.`waitinglist` (`newsletter`) VALUES ('$newsletter')";

Comment: it's still not working , when I submit it doesn't load

Comment: thnxxxxx.... you are my HERROOOO!!! hahah nice.. just one more question how can i check LIVE when the users enters an email if the email really exists?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding one more set of  tags in your html , include the div containing the checkbox in the existing form as the submit button should exist at only one place in the HTML file

If it still does not works, could you explain the error in more details.

Comment: this i my html now: <form method="post" action="waitinglist.php">
     <input type="text" name="waitingList" placeholder="Just enter your email :)">
     <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" value=1 checked />
     <label for="newsletter"><span></span>Get our monthly newsletter</label>
     <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Sign me up!">
    </form>

Comment: what should i do in my waitinglist.php because when i add $newsletter =(isset($_POST['newsletter'])?$_POST['newsletter']:'')

if($newsletter ==1){
  some code here....
} the page doesn't load anymore on submitting ... Some code here... what should i paste there?

Comment: thnxxxxx.... you are my HERROOOO!!! hahah nice.. just one more question how can i check LIVE when the users enters an email if the email really exists?

Answer (score 0):

some code here.... is not php code .You need to add actual PHP code for the action you need to take like

```
 $sql ="INSERT INTO robin.waitinglist (newsletter) VALUES ('$newsletter')";
```

Comment: thnx i did that but then when i add  $newsletter =(isset($_POST['newsletter'])?$_POST['newsletter']:'')  to my waitinglist.php it still blocks the whole submit proces and the page doesnt load on submit, i put it right at the top of my waitinglist.php under $waitingList as you can see in my first picture

Comment: wait i found it i forgot the ; at the end of it. so now i have the following problem if newsletter = checked i get a 1 in my DB but NO email , when i check it off i get an email and a empty newsletter column

Answer (score 0):

Make two more changes to the code

```
$newsletter =(isset($_POST['newsletter'])?$_POST['newsletter']:0)
```

and remove the code where you are checking for the value of $newsletter . Just have one sql in your code

Now you will have the email and either 1 or 0 for newsletter column in the table. Hope this resolves your issue

Comment: thnxxxxx.... you are my HERROOOO!!! hahah nice.. just one more question how can i check LIVE when the users enters an email if the email really exists?